# Java DST Change issue

Tags: java, timezone

I've found an issue about Java DST change. 
When the exact moment that DST(Daylight Saving time) happened, the certain time may appears two times.

For example, for the timezone America/Sao_Paulo, it changed backward one hour from Sunday, 21 February 2016, 00:00:00 to Saturday, 20 February 2016, 23:00:00.
The time 23:00 appears twice that day.

In my use case, I'd like to take the second time. For example, when I want the data of this day, I actually mean this day completely (even if maybe it contains 25 hours).

But in my opinion, it seems that Java take the first time of this moment.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testDSTChange() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");

    long dateInput = sdf.parse("2016-02-20T23:00:00").getTime();
    long dateUTC = dateInput - tz.getOffset(dateInput);

    long dateInput2 = sdf.parse("2016-02-21T02:00:00").getTime();
    long dateUTC2 = dateInput2 - tz.getOffset(dateInput2);

    System.out.println("Difference: " + (dateUTC2 - dateUTC) / 3600 / 1000);

}
```

In this example, it shows that the difference between these two dates is 4 hours, not the 3 hours that I expected. So I wonder that if there's any other way to do it ?

Comment: I don't understand clearly your question. You want that your time of that particular day not be affected by the hour change ?

Comment: No, I want the time that after the DST change. In my example, 2016-02-20T23:00:00 actually happens twice that day, I want to take the second one, the one after the DST change.

Comment: Are you able to use Joda Time or Java 8 instead of `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: What has changed in Java 8?

Comment: @Tony - A lot! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, the time at the DST change will occur twice when the DST changes backward, there is no way around it.  There may be another way around, but let me make a suggestion, internally use UTC time (GMT) it has no DST internally, convert to local time (wall clock time) on output for display purposes only.  You will never have to worry about it again.

Comment: The "use UTC for everything" advice is frequently given, but is an over-generalization. It's fine for *some* things, but not for others. If you want a weekly meeting starting at 3pm local time, for example, you really don't want to store that as "3pm local converted to UTC" - because then you lose the *real* information. So no, taking that approach certainly *doesn't* mean "you will never have to worry about it again".

Answer (score 0):

> In my use case, I'd like to take the second time. For example, when I want the data of this day, I actually mean this day completely (even if maybe it contains 25 hours).

From this statement, I'll assume you are actually doing some kind of range query to gather data over the entire day.  The best way to approach this is to query from the start of the day *inclusive*, to the start of the next day *exclusive*.  In other words:   `startOfDay <= dataPoint(s) < startOfNextDay`

This works well in your scenario, because the clock doesn't actually hit `00:00` until the next day has started.  It ticks like this:

```
23:58
23:59
23:00
23:01
...
23:58
23:59
00:00  <--- start of next day
```

So use half-open intervals, and it should just work out.

Do be careful in the spring transition though, when the start of the day is `01:00`, not `00:00`. :)

Also, Jon's comment about using Java 8's new time APIs, or Joda-Time are spot-on.  They both offer you better control over this situation.  Older Java APIs do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime l1 = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.FEBRUARY, 20, 23, 0, 0);
ZoneId id = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");  
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("-08:00");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(l1, offset, id);
long el1= zonedDateTime.toEpochSecond();



LocalDateTime l2 = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.FEBRUARY, 21, 2, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(l2, offset, id);;
long el2= zonedDateTime1.toEpochSecond();


System.out.println("Difference: " + (el2-el1 ) / 3600 );

    ====================================
    on console it prints 
    Difference: 3
```

Comment: It's better to include a brief explanation of the code and why it solves the problem, instead of only posting source.